# No mainmenu.xib file in Xcode 6.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xib

Build a new project in Xcode 6.3.1 for Mac using Cocoa and Objective-C.

mainmenu.xib is missing and when I create one, it creates it for iOS devices.

I am taking classes and this update messed me up.

Help!

Comment: When creating the file be sure to select Cocoa and not Cocoa Touch

Answer (score 0):

Here's a screenshot of how I do it in Xcode:

[image: New File]

I selected File -> New -> File (i.e. the "File" menu has a choice named "New" and a submenu choice named "File"), and this is the window that pops up.  Choose "User Interface" under OS X and "Empty" gives you an empty .xib file, or View gives you a xib file with a NSView object you can subclass.